# Thread Sleep in the Kafka Listener

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to pause/resume the Kafka container. Using the following code snippet to do so:

```
kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("MAIN").pause();
```

When I call the pause, I also need to do a thread.sleep so that messages in the batch are not processed. For every message in the batch, I am calling another API which has a rate limit. To maintain this rate limit, I need to stop the processing for the message.

If the Main thread sleeps, will it stop Listener from sending the hearbeat? Does it also stop the heartbeat thread in the background?
Documentation says , "When a container is paused, it continues to poll() the consumer, avoiding a rebalance if group management is being used, but it does not retrieve any records. "
But I am pausing the container and making the thread sleep. How will this impact the flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must never sleep the consumer thread, to avoid rebalancing.

Instead, reduce the `max.poll.records` so the pause will take effect more quickly (the consumer won't actually pause until the records received by the previous poll are processed).

You can throw an exception after pausing the consumer, but you will need to resume the container somehow.

I opened a new issue to improve this behavior https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2280

If you are subject to rate limits, consider using `KafkaTemplate.receive()` methods, on a schedule, or a polled [Spring Integration adapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/kafka.html#kafka-inbound-pollable), instead of using a message-driven approach.

Comment: Do you think I can spawn a child thread, make it sleep for some time and call container resume? The rate limit resets every 60s.

Comment: That would work; you can also add an event listener and resume the container if the container has been idle for the required interval. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#idle-containers

Comment: Thanks Gary. That was really helpful. I have one more question regarding the exception part. I have a bean ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory where I added  factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(1000L, 1L))).   I heard SeektoCurrentHandler is deprecated so I used that one instead. Can you let me know how throwing an exception would help? And where should the error be thrown?

Comment: Yes, that error handler replaces the old in with the same functionality. Just throw the exception after pausing the container.

Comment: @GaryRussell i am making the consumer sleep for 1 sec. because the initiated request gets saved in DB in 200-500 ms and before that if the kafka event comes for that record then consumer is not able to find it. So i have to wait(1s) till the record gets saved in DB. 
It works fine for few days but after that active consumer count in kafka drops to 0.
If i use different threads for each request and put sleep there then i may exhaust many threads and it can impact service performance.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; ask a new question showing code/configuration. You should never hand off work from the listener thread to another thread; it will cause problems with offsets and you will possibly lose records after a failure.